# In MySQL is there any function like "level" in Oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle

I'm facing a scenario, where if the input is 10, I want a sequence of numbers (1,2,3,...10).

In oracle the `level` function provides that function, and I wish to know how to perform the same task in MySQL.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You can Use this query in mysql

```
SET @rownr=0;
SELECT @rownr:=@rownr+1 AS `rowNumber` FROM `tablename` limit 10
```

the above query generate sequence of that number upto the limit.
Tablename is any of your table in db

Comment: Doesn't `tablename` need to have at least 10 rows in it?

Comment: what should we do if no table exist in db, and we don't want to create a new table? @Kannan Chakkara