# Reports month to month comparison chart over two years

Tags: mysql

i'm working on a small PHP and Mysql project and i want o show my sales of the two last years for example 2018 and 2019. how can i show all the months of the year
This is my sql query :

```
SELECT YEAR(b.creation_date) AS annee
 , MONTH(b.creation_date) AS mois
, SUM(price * quantity) AS total_ca 
  FROM invoicesitems a
  JOIN invoices b
 WHERE a.invoice_id = b.invoice_id 
    AND b.client = 6
GROUP BY YEAR(b.creation_date), MONTH(b.creation_date)
ORDER BY YEAR(b.creation_date), MONTH(b.creation_date)
```

And this is my result in English :

```
--------------------------
year | month | total_ca
--------------------------
2018 | 6     | 1548.00
--------------------------
2019 | 6     | 143.000
```

as you can see i have only month number 6 (june) how can i show all the months from 1 to 12.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - count by month (including missing records)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34557199/mysql-count-by-month-including-missing-records)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure you have values for invoices in others months and years.

Also, you have a mix of explicit and implicit join syntax; try using a proper explicit `ON` clause:

```
  SELECT YEAR(invoices.creation_date) AS annee
    , MONTH(invoices.creation_date) AS mois
    , SUM(price * quantity) AS total_ca 
  FROM invoicesitems 
  INNER JOIN invoices  ON  invoicesitems.invoice_id = invoices.invoice_id 
  WHERE invoices.client = 6
  GROUP BY YEAR(invoices.creation_date), MONTH(invoices.creation_date)
  ORDER BY YEAR(invoices.creation_date), MONTH(invoices.creation_date)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer first, but i'm still getting only month number 6 ( june )

Comment: then  based on your actual result  ..  update your question add  a proper data sample .. and you expected . result